# Powershell - is there a difference between `& .\monkeys.ps1` and `& powershell .\monkeys.ps1`?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, is there a difference between `& .\monkeys.ps1` and `& powershell .\monkeys.ps1` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'& .\monkeys.ps1' executes the script in the current console (session). '& powershell .\monkeys.ps1' opens up a new PowerShell process and executes the script.

Comment: And in the latter case the `&` is kinda redundant anyway.

Comment: Yup, it's redundant in the former as well (as long as the path doesn't contain spaces).

Comment: This makes a massive difference about `$LastExitCode`. The former doesn't set/alter it, the latter does.

Answer (score 0):

As well, if you check out the associate help file with powershell, you can see all the configurable options available with the powershell executable

```
powershell /?
```

This allows advanced functionality such as specifying window parameters, running commands directly from batch files, or running scripts (like above)